# removing last char comma not working

Tags: java

I am trying to remove last char of comma from a string using java.Here is my code,

```
//String feature=rs.getString("getvaluesfromDB");
String feature="Games-About Myself,Intro About Myself";
String [] b = feature.split("[\\-:\\;:\\,]");

for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++) {

    ResultSet rs2 = st2.executeQuery("select * from videonameslist where videoname='"+b[i]+"'");

    if(rs2.next()) {
        sbf.append("<a href='GameplayfromPlanner.jsp?sno="+b[i]+"' title='Click and Play this Game!' id='"+snoval+"' onclick='getIdforplaygame(this.id)'>").append(b[i]).append(",").append("</a>").append(" ");
    } else {
        sbf.append(b[i]).append(",").append(" ");
    }   

    System.out.println("befor  remove comma :"+sbf1);

    String sbf1 = sbf.toString();  

    if (sbf1.endsWith(",")) {
        sbf1 = sbf1.substring(0, sbf1.length() - 1); 
        System.out.println("after removing comma, the string is :"+sbf1);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Sorry there some proble in removing! :"+sbf1);
    }
```

Actually i am creating href tag to which data found from DB values.finally i am getting out put is,
before remove comma :`<a href='GameplayfromPlanner.jsp?sno=About Myself' title='Click and Play this Game!' id='9' onclick='getIdforplaygame(this.id)'>About Myself,</a> <a href='GameplayfromPlanner.jsp?sno=Intro About Myself' title='Click and Play this Game!' id='9' onclick='getIdforplaygame(this.id)'>Intro About Myself,</a>`

or sometimes output comes like this,
before remove comma :`<a href='GameplayfromPlanner.jsp?sno=Five senses' title='Click and Play this Game!' id='8' onclick='getIdforplaygame(this.id)'>Five senses,</a> Sense of touch,`

and condition always goes to else part.

Evan i tried

```
String sbf1 = sbf.toString(); sbf1 = sbf1.substring(0, sbf1.length() - 1);
```

**and**

```
if (sbf1.endsWith("</a>")) {
    sbf1 = sbf1.substring(0, sbf1.length() - 2); 
} else {
}
```

But no use

where i am wrong and how to fix this? (I am new to java)

Comment: Your code contains compile time errors, did you run it?

Comment: No i dont get any error!.

Comment: @RishiPrakash where you getting error?

Comment: well  System.out.println("befor  remove comma :"+sbf1);

    String sbf1 = sbf.toString();   ,using sbf1 before defining it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with 
    System.out.println("befor  remove comma :"+sbf);
            String sbf1 = sbf.toString().substring(0, sbf.length() - 5);
            System.out.println("sbf1 Rishi--->"+sbf1);
            if (sbf1.trim().endsWith(",")) {
                sbf1 = sbf1.trim().substring(0, sbf1.length() - 1); 
                sbf1+=""; 
                System.out.println("after removing comma, the string is :"+sbf1);
            }
Because your string ends with < / a>. Sorry bro, Lunch time. So just a dirty trick.

**FINAL EDIT :**

Your Problme is not the commas, but the way you are appending them. change your code with the modified code I am providing.

```
    //String feature=rs.getString("getvaluesfromDB");
    String feature="Games-About Myself,Intro About Myself";
    String [] b = feature.split("[\\-:\\;:\\,]");
    StringBuffer sbf = new StringBuffer();
    for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++) {

        ResultSet rs2 = st2.executeQuery("select * from videonameslist where videoname='"+b[i]+"'");

        if(rs2.next()) {
            if(sbf.length()==0){
                sbf.append("<a href='GameplayfromPlanner.jsp?sno="+b[i]+"' title='Click and Play this Game!' id='id' onclick='getIdforplaygame(this.id)'>").append(b[i]).append("</a>").append(" ");
            }else{
                sbf.append("<a href='GameplayfromPlanner.jsp?sno="+b[i]+"' title='Click and Play this Game!' id='id' onclick='getIdforplaygame(this.id)'>").append(",").append(b[i]).append("</a>").append(" ");
            }
        } else {
            if(sbf.length()==0){
                sbf.append(b[i]).append(" ");
            }else{
                sbf.append(",").append(b[i]).append(" ");
            }
        }  
        /*
         * No Need to remove commas
         * System.out.println("befor  remove comma :"+sbf1);
        String sbf1 = sbf.toString();  
        if (sbf1.endsWith(",")) {
            sbf1 = sbf1.substring(0, sbf1.length() - 1); 
            System.out.println("after removing comma, the string is :"+sbf1);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry there some proble in removing! :"+sbf1);
        }*/
}   
System.out.println("final sbf-->"+sbf);
```

Comment: Nice but some times needed words removing from long string.

Comment: for eg., give me a "long String" from which you need to remove comma.Tell me your problem specifically.

Comment: @manivasagam and If your problem is solved, you can accept my answer.

Comment: Lesson, <a href='GameplayfromPlanner.jsp?sno=Senses' title='Click and Play this Game!' id='8' onclick='getIdforplaygame(this.id)'>Senses,</a> Games, <a href='GameplayfromPlanner.jsp?sno=Intro About Myself' title='Click and Play this Game!' id='8' onclick='getIdforplaygame(this.id)'>Intro About Myself,</a> Worksheet, <a href='GameplayfromPlanner.jsp?sno=Five senses' title='Click and Play this Game!' id='8' onclick='getIdforplaygame(this.id)'>Five senses,</a> Sense of touch, 
in this string that last "uch" not printing.

Comment: @manivasagam I have changed your logic of appending commas, after that you don't need to remove commas. Check it out.

Comment: you did it!. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67322/discussion-between-manivasagam-and-rishi-prakash).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the string does not ends in `,` maybe after the comma there is a blank space, tab or something. Try:

```
if (sbf1.trim().endsWith(",")) {
```

Comment: No!.Even this not working.Actually that string some times ends with </a> or comma(,).

Comment: I don't understand your question. If the string ends with </a> then what is removing a comma at the end supposed to do?

Comment: @pbabcdefp actually he was trying to remove the comma which comes before < /a> tag.

Comment: @pbabcdefp yes Rishi saying is my question.

Comment: @Rishi Prakash Oh right, thanks. BTW I don't think `sbf1.trim().substring(0, sbf1.length() - 1)` is right. You're trying to take one character off `sbf1.trim()` but using one less than the length of `sbf1`.

Comment: yes so is there any solution to remove comma if ends with comma or remove comma before that </a> char.?

Comment: @pbabcdefp problem is not the commas, but they way in which he is appending them.